# checking whether a file with header is empty

Tags: vba, excel, runtime-error

I am writing a VBA code to check whether some other files are empty or not. These files all have headers so I want to check whether the "A2" cell is empty or has a zero length. My code is below, file1, dir1, dirfile1 are filename, directory, path. I am also having a problem whether I do need to open the file in order to access its "A2" cell.

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

Dim file1, dir1, dirfile1 As String

file1 = "NAMBS." & Range("f3")
dir1 = Range("D11")
dirfile1 = dir1 & "\" & file1

Range("F14").Clear

If Len(Dir(dirfile1)) = 0 Then
    Range("F14") = "missing"
Else
    Workbooks.Open (dirfile1)
    If IsEmpty(ThisWorkbook.Sheets(dirfile1).Range("a2")) Then
        Range("F14") = "empty"
    End If
    Workbooks(file1).Close
End If
End Sub
```

The error msg is run-time error '9': Subscript out of range. Basically, I want to access "A2" cell in another table and check whether empty or not and then close it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting a workbook object type variable when you open the file.

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    Dim file1 As String, dir1 As String, dirfile1 As String
    Dim wbo As Workbook

    With ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
        file1 = "NAMBS." & .Range("f3")
        dir1 = .Range("D11")
        dirfile1 = dir1 & "\" & file1

        .Range("F14").Clear

        If Len(Dir(dirfile1)) = 0 Then
            .Range("F14") = "missing"
        Else
            Set wbo = Workbooks.Open(dirfile1)
            If IsEmpty(wbo.Sheets(1).Range("a2")) Then
                .Range("F14") = "empty"
            End If
            wbo.Close , False
            Set wbo = Nothing
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

All cell range references are referred back to the parent determined by the `With/End With` block. The opened workbook is referred to explicitly by the `wbo` variable assigned to the workbook object.

If these files are CSVs and they all have a common header, then check the file size for anything larger than a header-only file and you won't have to open them to determine if they are populated.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your suggestions. This is indeed a good way. But then I got another error. Compile error: Method or data member not found. I searched around but didn't find out how to solve this one. I like the second method very much but it doesn't work for my case as for very few times, the file with headers only have almost the same size as a non-empty file.

Comment: The With/End With requires that the worksheet be set, not just the workbook. Adjusted above.